# Are direct reads possible in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Oracle has this concept of direct reads, where a session reads data from a table directly into its session memory bypassing buffer cache. Is something similar possible in postgres? Does a session always gets data from shared buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up two things.

- the kernel cache where the kernel caches files to serve reads and writes more efficiently
- the database shared memory cache (shared buffers) where the database caches table and index blocks

All database use the latter (Oracle calls it “database buffer cache”), because without caching performance would be abysmal.

With direct I/O you avoid the kernel cache, that is, all read and write requests go directly to disk.

There is no way in PostgreSQL to use direct I/O.

However, it has been recognized that buffered I/O comes with its own set of problems (e.g., a write request may succeed, a sync request that tells the kernel to flush the data to disk may fail, but the next sync request for the same (unpersisted!) data may not return an error any more). Relevant people hold the opinion that it might be a good idea to move to direct I/O eventually to avoid having to deal with such problems, but that would be a major change, and I wouldn't hold my breath until it happens.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz Albe, in my situation I am dealing with a massive OLAP database on AWS RDS PostgreSQL. Most of the queries access massive tables that are unique to the session. And by default RDS allocates 70% of memory to shared buffers, but in my case allocating more memory to sessions would help more. So that's where I was thinking of using direct IO if possible. Since its not, I would have to go to with reducing shared_buffers to free up memory to sessions.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. You will actually benefit from buffered I/O that way: any RAM not used by backend processes will automatically be used for caching.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe *"All database use the latter (Oracle calls it “database buffer cache”)"* in fact, Oracle has a mechanism for bypassing its buffer cache for very big objects since 11g: "adaptive serial direct reads". And even before that it was used for parallel queries.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov Oracle may avoid caching certain data (PostgreSQL also has strategies to avoid blowing out the cache with large sequential scans), but it still uses a shared memory cache, right?

Comment: No, Direct reads bypass the buffer cache

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov Of course. But it has an SGA, right? That is a shared memory segment, used to cache blocks. I guess we are talking past each other.

Comment: Buffer cache is located in SGA, but direct reads bypass it and send data directly to non-shared session memory

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov But direct I/O is also used to read data into the SGA, right? That's the case I was talking about. Perhaps I was not clear enough.

Comment: I just corrected the second statement - re buffer cache ("adaptive direct reads"), that was not about FS I/O - this is another big topic (it's too big to cover it here) and there is another parameter for that - `FILESYSTEMIO_OPTIONS`: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/direct-and-asynchronous-io